# Fail to enable synchronized access though transaction is in place

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, wcf

I am not able to  achieve a synchronized data access on a data table even though I have `TransactionScope` in place.

I have a WCF service, which is responsible for accessing a serialized object graph, which is stored in a SQL database; and this is been achieved through an operation contract called `GetObject`, where it returns a serialized object from table using given `tokenId`. The tokenId is relevant in our scenario to ensure that, no two user have access on a same row (object graph) at any point in time.

And when it comes to wcf service, our service is multithreaded (`Cuncurrency` is `Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode` is `PerCall`).

```
public CustomObject GetObject(string username, string userTeam)
{
     int tokenID = Database.GetNextToken(username, userTeam);

     MainDataLayer.LoadData loadData = new MainDataLayer.LoadData();
     return loadData.GetObject (tokenID);
}
```

The `GetNextToken(tokenID)` calls a `CLR stored procedure` to access the database table within a transaction scope.

```
 public static void usp_GetNextToken(SqlString userID, SqlString userTeam)
  {
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection = true"))
      {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[1]
        {
          new SqlMetaData("objectId", SqlDbType.Int)
        });

SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("SELECT top (1) * FROM myTable where lockedby= ' ' ORDER BY createdate DESC ", connection));


          DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
          if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
          ((DataAdapter) sqlDataAdapter2).Fill(dataSet2);

          if (dataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
          {
            new SqlCommand(string.Concat(new object[4]
            {
              (object) "UPDATE myTable SET lockedby = '",
              (object) userID.ToString(),
              (object) "' WHERE objectId = ",
              (object) int.Parse(dataSet2.Tables[0].Rows[0][" objectId "].ToString())
            }), connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
            record.SetSqlInt32(0, (SqlInt32) int.Parse(dataSet2.Tables[0].Rows[0][" objectId "].ToString()));
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record);
            return;
          }
        }
        record.SetSqlInt32(0, (SqlInt32) 0);
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record);
      }
      transactionScope.Complete();
    }
  }
```

**Question**
Having all these in place, we at most cases end up having multiple user accessing same object graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. TransactionScope is only in place so you can commit or rollback you SQL statements.

I figure you can use `lock` to prevent multiple requests being handeld:

```
private static object DatabaseLock = new object();

public CustomObject GetObject(string username, string userTeam)
{
    lock (DatabaseLock)
    {
        int tokenID = Database.GetNextToken(username, userTeam);

        MainDataLayer.LoadData loadData = new MainDataLayer.LoadData();
        return loadData.GetObject (tokenID);
    }
}
```

This will impact performance however.

Is is not simpler to create a Service with the `Concurrency` set to `Single`?

Comment: How about using the BeginTransaction method with the IsolationLevel parameter on the SqlConnection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx | http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx